# How do I manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure-a'?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to install CrossOver using the Terminal app. I typed in the following command line 'sudo apt install //crossover_22.1.0-1.deb'. I received two (2) error messages. The first was 'unsupported file given on command line. The second was dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: I have converted my comments to a full answer. Accept it as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will indicate your problem is solved and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

## How do I manually run `sudo dpkg --configure-a`?

1. Open a terminal (if none is open). You can do this by searching for the app called **Terminal** or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Enter the command as shown in the error message. It is best to copy and paste where possible. The commands and file and folder names are case sensitive in Ubuntu. `apt` and `APT` and `aPt` are three different things.

Here is the command again. It may be easier to copy from here:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and you will be prompted to type your password. When you type the password the cursor will not move and you will **NOT** see any `*********`. This is normal. After entering the password press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Now you have manually run that command.

## Error: `Unsupported file given on command line`

The `//crossover_22.0.1-1.deb` is wrong.

Specifically `//` does not make any sense in this context. Probably that's why you get the first error.

**If the file was downloaded in the current folder,** the correct command is:

```
sudo apt install ./crossover_22.0.1-1.deb
```

**Note,** there is no space between the dot `.` and the slash `/` and the file name `crossover_22.0.1-1.deb`

**If the file was downloaded in the Downloads folder,** the correct command is:

```
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/crossover_22.0.1-1.deb.
```

**Note,** there is no space between the tilde `~` and the first slash `/`.

Hope this helps